# Unshelve a file which is in exclusive check out in Perforce/P4

Tags: locking, perforce, unshelve, shelving

Perforce noob here - I have a file on a shelf which I want to unshelve to run a few things, however the file is exclusively checked out on another machine. Ideally what I want to do is unshelve the file locally, do a few things, then toss out my local changes.

I considered using `p4 print` and `p4 copy` but they don't seem to work as required - e.g. copy seems to copy files between depot paths.

How can I unshelve and ignore the lock? Alternatively, how can I download the file from the shelve to overwrite it locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use `p4 print FILE@=SHELF` to get the content of the file.  This is very straightforward for one file but will be annoying for multiple files.
2. Create a new branch/stream and unshelve it there; the exclusive lock isn't global across branches so you can do whatever you want in your own branch.

With streams option 2 looks like:

```
p4 switch -c my-new-stream
p4 unshelve -S my-new-stream -s SHELF
```

With manual branch specs it looks more like (assuming your client maps everything, if not there's an extra step of adding the new branch to your client mapping):

```
p4 branch my-new-branch
(fill in a view mapping the current branch to your new branch)
p4 copy -b my-new-branch
p4 submit
p4 unshelve -b my-new-branch -s SHELF
```

Comment: Another option might be to use 'p4 clone' to take the files into a DVCS sandbox, and work on them there.

Comment: Wanted to come back to add one important detail to using `p4 print`: if you need the file written somewhere, use the `-o <output file>` flag so you get the file outputted as-is. Copy/paste or capturing the command window output in a script will give ASCII outputs, and will ruin the encoding on non-ASCII data (e.g. binary zeroes will become ASCII 20s).